# PHP Routing Not Working In Second Level of URL Parameter

Tags: php, routes

I am using this code for simple PHP routing system

```
the `.htaccess` file is like this:

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The `index.php` file is like

```
<?php
        $url_requested = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $url_len = strlen($url_requested);
        
        $actual_path = substr($url_requested,strpos($url_requested,'/'),$url_len); 
    
        if($actual_path == "/"){
            include_once('./home.php');
        }    
        else if(preg_match("!/products/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]!",$actual_path)){
            $actual_route = substr($actual_path,(strrpos($actual_path,'/')+1),$url_len);
            $actual_route = str_replace("%20"," ",$actual_route);  
            $data_arr = [
                'content_to_show' => $actual_route
            ];      
            include_once('./products.php');
        }
        else if($actual_path == "/products"){        
            include_once('./products.php');
        }
        else if($actual_path == "/solutions"){
            include_once('./solutions.php');
        }    
        else {
            include_once('./404.php');
        }
    ?>
```

The `products.php` page is like

```
<body>
        <?php include_once('./navbar.php'); ?>
    
        <?php
            if(isset($data_arr) && !empty($data_arr)){
        ?>
            <div class="div_for_content">
            You are viewing<br/><br/>
            <?php echo $data_arr['content_to_show']; ?>
            page
                </div>
        <?php
        }
        else {
        ?>
        <p style="margin-top:50px;">This is products page.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/products/product 1">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/product 2">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/product 3">Product 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/product 4">Product 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/product 5">Product 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </body>
```

And the `solutions.php` looks like

```
<body>
   <?php include_once('./navbar.php'); ?>
   <p style="margin-top:50px;">This is solutions page.</p>
</body>
```

now when navigating to URLS like

```
http://website/home
http://website/solutions
http://website/products
```

things work properly but when trying `http://website/products/product 1` I am still seeing the product partial view!

I tried to dump the `$data_arr` out of the `if(isset($data_arr) && !empty($data_arr)){}` and noticed that it is not even been set!

Can you please let me know how to fix this

[image]

Comment: you send product 1 with space, but you have in preg_match not allowed spaces, also you should send without spaces like product-1 with url_encode its more safe

Comment: But even when I am passing `product-1` same thing is happening

Comment: i think you need remove ! from regex and add space \s and make valid regex preg_match("\/products\/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/g",$actual_path))